# Construction of another regular pentagon

Tags: geometric-construction

I have a problem that involves construction with the ruler and compass. I want to prove more constructions of the regular pentagon. I finished demonstrating some more constructions, but I couldn’t do one of them.
Here is the problem: considering the following points in plan $O(0,0)$, $A(-\frac{1}{2},0)$  and $B(0,1)$.  The bisector of the angle $OAB$ intersects the axis $Oy$ in the point $D$. Then, we intersect the horizontal line, which intersects the point $D$ with the trigonometric circle.
What I want to prove is that this construction gives us the side of the regular pentagon.
I will be grateful if you could help me with some suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This image from Wikipedia confirms that it does:

[Richmond's construction of pentagon side](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentagon#/media/File:Richmond_pentagon_1.PNG)